# Что нужно знать чтобы учить python django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

2,5 месяца назад я заинтересовался программированием и начал учить пайтон. Спустя некоторое время я начал понимать что мне больше нравится веб-разработка. Так как я ещё мало знаю, я хотел бы спросить что мне нужно знать чтобы учить python django?

P.S Мне 13 лет, если это важно

Comment: Основы питона + английский, чтобы читать доки по джанге + умение пользоваться Гуглом и различными форумами на подобие so. Ну и практики много. А так если чисто бэк то больше ничего

Comment: Возраст самый подходящий для начинающего разработчика. Много практики по веб-разработке доступно на сайтах фрилансеров. И в этой сфере IT желательно работать небольшой командой, если такая возможность есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня есть опыт преподавания программирования, поэтому могу сказать, что достаточно основ Питона (хотя бы понимание число/строк, списков, словарей, функций и классов) и возраст не важен, куда важнее наличие большой, долго живущей мотивации, чтобы старательно разбираться в новых темах и много практиковаться. Также будет большим плюсом хотя бы какое-то знание английского и умение гуглить, самостоятельно искать ответы на сложные вопросы.

В веб-разработке разных тем надо учить много, и поначалу ничего не понятно – это может отталкивать, но на самом деле всё не так страшно, т.к, во-первых, в наше время в интернете полно ответов на все вопросы, а во-вторых, не обязательно знать всё и сразу, многие вещи можно изучать и запоминать постепенно, в границах необходимых для решения конкретной задачи. С опытом запоминаться будет всё больше и глубже.

> На самом деле, тем реально много, и они очень глубокие; но и правда, что это всё не обязательно знать досконально – нередко разработчики разбираются в каких-то вопросах лишь поверхностно, а код просто копируют и адаптируют с блогов и StackOverflow. Это в принципе норм для начала, но надо понимать, что норм это *только* для начала, и по возможности стоит проявлять интерес, разбираться в вопросах глубже и таким образом значительно повышать свою квалификацию. Но это так, на будущее ;)

Стоит использовать какую-нибудь книгу или курс по Django для начинающих, например [Django Girls](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/). И важно научиться не ограничиваться одним источником информации, т.к скорее всего там не всё описано достаточно подробно и понятно, а альтернативные материалы (другие книги, просто статьи или даже ответы на StackOverflow) могут это успешно компенсировать.

Также возможно стоит использовать Django 2.2 – третья версия имеет заметные отличия, и материалов по ней пока не так много. А в целом – удачи в построении карьеры, the world is your oyster!

Comment: Большое спасибо, английский я сейчас активно изучаю, сдаваться я не собираюсь и из основ я не учил ещё только классы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну пожалуй зависит от того, что вам надо бэк или фронт. Хотя вот пожалуй:

- Python & Django (вы уже изучаете)
- [HTML CSS JavaScript](https://habr.com/ru/post/275729/) (фронт)
- [SQL](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) DB (бэк)
- [Bash](https://linuxgeeks.ru/bash-1.htm)  (управлять своим линуксом на высоком уровне)
- Умение гуглить
- Если хотите понимать интернет на низком уровне: сокеты, tcp и т.д.
- English language

Comment: BASH прямо глубоко не нужно изучать (это больше для администрирования или DevOps нужно, но не так уж нужно для backend).

Comment: @insolor Ну основы по мне всем нужны.